# B2B Shop with Colors and Variants as a Matrix

Tags: shopping-cart, responsive, b2b

Hey guys we've a B2B Shop.
In the Item View you can order multiple Items depending on which Color and Variant it is.

below you'll see two screenshots where you can order for each variant and color and another one where you are only able to order some specific combinations between colors and variants

[image: many variants with 2 Colors]

[image]

Now my questions:
What would you do to optimize the view to make the shopping experience a bit less painful?
And on the other hand - this is a full responsive shop - how to deal with a mobile device in such situations?

Our current solution is pictured in the 3rd image below

[image: Our current solution is pictured in the 3rd image below]

Comment: What do the numbers below the input boxes represent?

Comment: current warehouse stock

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the incrementing controls from the quantity inputs. The `number` HTML input type supports this by default, so it's probably unnecessary. Having users use the mouse to increment or decrement something is going to very slow. Ideally, you'd have the ability to exclusively use your keyboard for this whole process (tabbing left/right, incrementing/decrementing with the up/down arrow keys). Nielsen Norman Group wrote a [good article](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/keyboard-accessibility/) about keyboard controls and accessbily that has, I think, some relevant information.

I might change the layout to make color/variant the column and size the row; I don't have any research to support this, but my feeling is that a correct fit is more important than color to most customers. Prioritizing sizing lets you scan and tab quickly across a row, and, I think, would speed up data entry.

It might also be helpful to add some sort of supporting visual element to the column headers to help users scan the columns more easily. In my example below I've used a colored circle, but it really could be anything.

[image]

Comment: What would you do to make that mobile responsive?